# how to separate user/admin page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to separate user/admin login

```
          if ($user_id) 
          {
            //Create Session
            $user_data = array(
                  'user_id' => $user_id->id,
                  'username' => $username,
                  'email' => $user_id->email,
                  'name' =>$name,
                  'login' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

            if($user_data['username'] != 'Admin');
            {
              $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in.');
           redirect('users/dashboard');
            }
            if($user_data['username'] == 'Admin');
            {
            //Set Message
           $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in.');
           redirect('users/admin_dashboard');}

          }
          else
          {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid.');
            redirect('users/login');
          }              
          }
```

it tells else condition error. please suggest
any other way to solve this error. what mistake i have done.

Comment: Try counting the `{}` brackets: you have four opening brackets `{` and five closing brackets `}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you have an extra closing brackets

```
if ($user_id) 
              {
                //Create Session
                $user_data = array(
                      'user_id' => $user_id->id,
                      'username' => $username,
                      'email' => $user_id->email,
                      'name' =>$name,
                      'login' => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

                if($user_data['username'] != 'Admin');
                {
                  $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in.');
               redirect('users/dashboard');
                }
                if($user_data['username'] == 'Admin');
                {
                //Set Message
               $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in.');
               redirect('users/admin_dashboard');

              }
              else
              {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid.');
                redirect('users/login');
              }              
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

if($user_data['username'] == 'Admin');
it is error.
 if($user_data['username'] == 'Admin')
. and also add closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. You had some typos.

```
if ($user_id) 
      {
        //Create Session
        $user_data = array(
              'user_id' => $user_id->id,
              'username' => $username,
              'email' => $user_id->email,
              'name' =>$name,
              'login' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

        if($user_data['username'] != 'Admin');
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in.');
          redirect('users/dashboard');
        }
        else if($user_data['username'] == 'Admin');
        {
          //Set Message
          $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in.');
          redirect('users/admin_dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid.');
         redirect('users/login');
        }              
     }
```